# Exposing boost::scoped_ptr in boost::python

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers, boost-python

I am getting a compile error, saying that the copy constructor of the `scoped_ptr` is private with the following code snippet:

```
class a {};

struct s
{
  boost::scoped_ptr<a> p;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( module )
{
  class_<s>( "s" );
}
```

This example works with a shared_ptr though. It would be nice, if anyone knows the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The semantics of `boost::scoped_ptr` prohibit taking copies, while `shared_ptr` is intended to be copied. The error you are getting is the compiler telling you that some of the code (macro expansion?) is trying to copy the `scoped_ptr` but that the library does not allow the copy to be made.